# Count all elements until next element with same class name appears

Tags: jquery

I need to get the number of all `windows-detail-spec-label` in between two `windows-detail-spec-group` classes in the folowing table layout - so I can use that number for rearanging the table on different screen sizes.

How can I count them so I get the correct number out?

For the first set of elements it should be `2` since `windows-detail-spec-label` appers twice inbetwen (note: next `windows-detail-spec-group` is in the second `.row-label` `tr`)

[image: table html layout]

My current code:

```
$('.windows-details-spec-group').each(function () {

  var rowspanCount = $(this).nextUntil('.windows-details-spec-group').filter('.windows-details-spec-label').length;

  $(this).unwrap().next('tr.row-default').prepend(this);
  $(this).attr({
      colspan: 1,
      rowspan: rowspanCount  // need this variable to be correct
  });
});
```

So basically I need to count how many times a class appears between two elements **no matter where in the DOM in between**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to make some additional reasonable assumptions regarding the structure of the DOM near the points of interest -- "no matter where in the DOM" is too generic and you 'd have a very hard time actually implementing it properly.

Assuming that any `td.windows-details-spec-group` is going to be the only child of its parent row and the same for `td.windows-details-spec-label` (which certainly seems to be the case here) you can do it like this:

```
$('.windows-details-spec-group').each(function () {
    var rowspan = $(this)
                  .closest("tr")
                  .nextUntil("tr:has(.windows-details-spec-group)")
                  .find(".windows-details-spec-label")
                  .length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $('.windows-details-spec-group').each(function () {

          var rowspanCount = $(this).nextUntil('.windows-details-spec-group').find(".windows-detail-spec-label").length;

          $(this).attr({
              colspan: 1,
              rowspan: rowspanCount  // need this variable to be correct
          });
        });
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/NNfmS/